# restoring using timeshift with an encrypted disk from a fresh live usb install

Tags: fstab, pop-os, restore, crypttab, timeshift

if you're using the live usb (this is specific to pop!_os 21.04, but i think it would apply to ubuntu etc) and you do a fresh reinstall, would you need to boot into the new system to get access to the newly created /etc/fstab file (and crypttab file?), and if not, how do you access it from the live usb after the fresh install? would you simply  unencrypt the drive, mount, and then grab a copy there?

or another way to go about it would be to use a copy of `/etc/fstab` (and `/etc/crypttab` ?) from a timeshift snapshot and edit it. then simply restore the edited `/etc/fstab` (and `/etc/crypttab`? ) with timeshift.

this question is in response to the following answer:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/636712/497219